# Mootools: How to stop browser from freezing when Request is sent

Tags: javascript, mootools, javascript-framework

i am developing an application. 
On a form submit i am sending a request to server using Request class in mootools. 
but when i click on submit button it freezes browser, till the response comes from server.
The ResponseText is sent to a custom function responseProcessor() for processing on it.

The Request Object is like:

```
 req = new Request({
    async: true, method: 'post',
    onSuccess: function(html) { responseProcessor(); },
    onFailure: function() { alert('Page Loading Failed ....!!'); },
 });
 req.send({url: "js/jsCode.php"});
```

I cant figure out why browser is freezing while Request takes place?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with that code, it shouldn't freeze your browser.  Have you considered posting to http://jsfiddle.net?  is it just this request or all requests?  Also not that async defaults to true, so no need to include it in your options.

Answer (score 3):

your request is synchronous, so the browser will freeze until the request completes.

set async: true to resolve this

Comment: i tried to put `async: true` but its not helping me in solving the issue.

Comment: If so, then your browser is freezing because of a script looping infinitely.

with Firefox+firebug, when your browser is freezing you get an alert box that offers you to see where the code hangs.